# How can I seed data into Rails5 engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-engines

Based on [edgeapi.rubyonrails.org](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html#label-Migrations+&+seed+data) explanation, I try to initialize base data in my rails engine (Glossary). I created 2 files:

> db/seed.rb

```
if Glossary::Parameter.count==0
puts "Creating parameters"
Glossary::Parameter.create(name: 'Lines to display', value: '20', list: 'Display')
Glossary::Parameter.create(name: 'Undefined category', value: 'Undefined', list: 'Categories')
end
```

and

> spec/dummy/seed.rb

```
Glossary::Engine.load_seed
```

When I run `rake db:seed` from either the root location or the spec/dummy location, nothing happens.
But the records count and creation works fine when executed in the console.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

```
rake db:seed_engine
```

or

```
rails db:seed_engine
```

Comment: rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:seed_engine'

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake: the name of the file containing the seeds is **seeds.rb**, with a S.

So the solution is:

1-Update the **spec/dummy/db/seeds.rb** file of the containing application:

```
Glossary::Engine.load_seed
```

2-In the **db/seeds.rb** file of the engine, create your seeds:

```
if Glossary::Parameter.count==0
puts "Creating parameters"
Glossary::Parameter.create(name: 'Lines to display', value: '20', list: 'Display')
Glossary::Parameter.create(name: 'Undefined category', value: 'Undefined', list: 'Categories')
end
```

3-In the console, jump to the spec/dummy/ folder, and run `rake db:seed` command.

Answer (score -1):

Your engine's `seed.rb` has to live on its `db/` folder. [Here's an excellent example](https://github.com/taskrabbit/rails_engines_example) of a rails app with different engines.

Comment: engine seed.rb is exactly there, in db/ engine's folder. What is discussed about migrations in the example works fine, but there's nothing about seeding ...